# Measuring the angle between skew coordinate axes using the skew coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, coordinate-systems

My application is that I have a cheap Chinese CNC machine where the X and Y axes are not quite orthogonal. They are close, but not quite there, and I'd like to measure the angle between the axes so as to adjust the machine and bring them closer to being orthogonal.

Translating (as best I can) into maths, we have a skew coordinate system where x' = x, and y' is at an angle (close to pi/2) from x. We can make marks in x' and y', and we can measure accurately in x' and y' (I use a microscope and a small drill bit, and move the bit until it is over the mark). But we cannot make marks in x,y, nor can we measure (nearly as) accurately in x,y.

I've already figured out that what I do is drill three holes in a piece of waste material at (x',y') = (0,0) (a,0) (0,b), then take that piece of waste material, flip it in y, and measure where the three holes appear on the other side. Of course we won't be able to quite flip it in y - there will be a different small angle between the y axis and the actual axis of reflection (it's a really cheap machine!).

So I measure the three holes post-flip at (0,0) (a',0) and (0,b') (NO - SEE BELOW!). Now I'm going to assume that the x' and y' axes on my machine have the same scale. How do I go from a, b, a' and b' to the angle (let's call it theta) between the x' and y' axes? Especially since I don't know the precise angle between the axis of reflection and the y axis (let's call it psi)? I've looked at this geometrically and I believe it should be possible, but the I keep making mistakes when I try and do the maths.

Thanks.

EDIT: OK I'm an idiot. Post-flip the holes will be at (0,0) (a'x, a'y) and (b'x, b'y). Both a'y and b'x should be close to zero, but they will not be zero!

CLARIFICATION: I'm aiming for an accuracy of 50 micrometers across 100 millimeters or better. I seem to be able to measure and cut with that accuracy, and it is an accuracy I need for my ultimate application (double-sided PCB milling).

My thoughts: There are four translations involved. We go from (x',y') to (x,y), then to (-x,y), then through a rotation psi, then to our new (x',y'). That's four matrix multiplications, whose result I imagine would be a mess! Then trying to solve for theta (and probably psi) would also be a mess! I'm wondering if an iterative approach would be better? Given psi figure out how to calculate theta, and given theta figure out how to calculate psi? Because we can make a good initial guess of psi = 0 and theta = pi/2.

Edit: There are suggestions that I use a caliper to take measurements and then apply simple geometry to find the answer. I've done a very quick test - getting my caliper to make sub-50-micrometer movements while keeping it still enough so that it doesn't drift off the far hole is really difficult - calipers are built to butt up against measurement points. I'd have to get machined pins and matching drill bits or something. What I might do is take advantage of the power of computers, and write some silly code using a generic minimising algorithm. That would have advantages that I could throw more data points at it, it would do its best with any inaccuracies in measurement, it could handle any other misalignments in the CNC machine (though the machine seems to be quite well aligned otherwise), and it could give me error estimates. Thanks.

Comment: I think it would be easier to calculate angles in your triangle (using law of cosines, for example) formed by the three holes and see what adjustments are needed

Comment: Sounds good. But I need to put numbers on those adjustments. I don't want to have to depend on an iterative process where I keep drilling holes and flipping the piece around.

Comment: No need to flip the piece, three holes should be enough, just make sure the holes are as far as possible to improve accuracy of calculations. You need to measure three distances between all holes, can you do that?

Comment: That's something I'll need to investigate. At the moment, the answer is "no" - I need to use the CNC to make measurements. However I own some calipers - if I can use them to make measurements to the required accuracy I guess it's the easiest way to go. I'll set up some practice runs as soon as I can. Note that I've since edited my question above and put my thinking about an approach on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you drill holes at $(x',y')$ coordinates $(0,0),$ $(a,0),$ $(-a,0),$ and $(b,0),$ then cut the piece in two along the line $x'=0,$ using a thin enough saw that part of each hole along that line is still visible in each piece. Put both pieces upright with the cut edge supported by rollers in each of the holes. (Use rollers of a slightly smaller diameter than the drill, resting on a flat surface.) This will effectively "fold" the piece along the line $x'=0,$ and the error in the angle between the axes will be measurable by the distance between the centers of the $(\pm a,0)$ holes.

Specifically, if the distance between the centers of the $(\pm a,0)$ holes
is $d$ after "folding" the piece, the angle between the axes of the machine is
$$\frac\pi2 \pm \arcsin\frac{2a}{d}.$$

You can deduce which sign to use for the $\pm$ by seeing in which direction the holes are offset.

This being such a poorly made machine, you might want to use your own instruments to measure the distances between the center of the hole drilled at $(x',y')=(0,0)$ and the centers of the $(\pm a,0)$ holes. If the measurements are the same you can substitute the new measurement for the value $a$ calibrated by the machine, though this probably will have little impact on the calculated angle.
More important is that if you find a difference in the measurements that is within a couple of orders of magnitude of $d,$ you may want to take that into account in the formula.
Mathematically, the angle could be found via the Law of Cosines in that case,
but in practice the arc cosine of a very small angle tends to be miscalculated;
instead, a good approximation would be to set $d_1 = \sqrt{d^2 - (a_1 - a_2)^2},$ where $a_1$ and $a_2$ are the two measurements, and then the angle is
$$\frac\pi2 \pm \arcsin\frac{a_1 + a_2}{d_1},$$

or even
$$\frac\pi2 \pm \frac{a_1 + a_2}{d_1}$$
since the angle is (apparently) small enough to make this a good approximation.

Comment: I'm trying to do this to an accuracy of 50 micrometers per 100mm or better, as I can (and need to for my ultimate application - PCB milling) measure to that accuracy on the CNC. So the holes / saw would have to be impractically small. I actually don't have a saw that thin, and I'm not sure it would even be possible for such a saw to cut!

Comment: You don't need the holes to be small, just to be the same size. You also need the rollers to be exactly the same size. The requirement for 50 um accuracy may change things; I'm coming from a pre-CNC world where we put a blued piece on a granite slab to mark it with a stylus. So I guess you have to use the CNC machine itself to do the measurements, and trust that (other than the angle between the axes) it does everything consistently; is that a correct understanding of the problem?

Comment: Yes I'll be using the CNC machine to measure the distances. And if the CNC machine isn't consistent then I have bigger problems! I guess I could in theory use calipers to do the measurements. For reasons I can't put my finger on at the moment that idea makes me uneasy, but I'll think about it. Note that I've since edited my question above. Thanks.

Comment: Thinking about the (very old) Vernier calipers I own, I would worry that only the very tip of the calipers would fit in the CNC hold, and the tip is sharp and would cut into the PCB material, rendering the measurement inaccurate. If you could put metal pins in the holes (to contact the hole's edge without cutting it) it might help. If you can make accurate measurements between holes using an instrument independent of the CNC, you do something like the suggestion in one of the comments where you don't even have to flip the board.

Comment: Another thought: for some methods (like the one in Vasya's comment), you don't even need your independent measurements to be very accurate--you just need the _difference_ between two almost-identical measurements to be very accurate. E.g., drill holes at the vertices of a 100 mm square and measure the diagonal distances; if one diagonal is 460 um longer than the other then you can make a very good estimate of how far out of true the "right angles" are.

Comment: As I said to Vasya I'll need to set up some practice runs to see how accurately I can measure with the calipers. I'm not sure why I'd need to fit the calipers into the CNC machine - surely I can drill the holes, take the piece out, measure, and deduce what needs to happen to make the axes orthogonal? I don't mind 2 or 3 iterations to get it right.

Comment: I was thinking of taking the piece out for the measurements after all the holes are drilled. You can accept an unknown error in all the measurements you make outside the CNC, as long as the error is the same for each measurement. It's the part where you have to get the error to be the same every time that I think would be the most troublesome.

Answer (score 0):

This solution will work even if $x'$ and $y'$ are not of the same scale, or the machine's true axes are far from orthogonal.

Drill holes $O,A,B$ at $(x',y')=(0,0),(0,p),(p,0)$ for any convenient $p$. Measure the side lengths of $\triangle AOB$ as $AO=a,OB=b,AB=c$.

$\theta$, the angle between the machine's axes, is $\angle AOB$ and can be found with the cosine rule. Since precision is demanded, a numerically stable variant should be used:
$$\theta=2\sin^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{(c+a-b)(c+b-a)}{4ab}}$$

Comment: @DavidK hm, but the angle here is expected to be close to 90°. If I was using the cross product and the arcsine instead, I would have large numerical instabilities.

Comment: Oops. I took the approach of calculating the _difference_ between the actual angle and a right angle, so of course I was dealing with small angles. But since you're taking the inner product (obvious when I actually read the right-hand side of the formula!), and getting a result near zero, arc cosine is fine. The drawing of an accurate Cartesian grid might be quite a task, however.

Comment: I'll need to get something which produces a cartesian grid I can trust and which is more accurate than what the CNC can measure/drill. I'm hoping to get 50 micrometers per 100mm or better, as I seem to be able to measure to at least that accuracy. So I'm not sure where I can get a cartesian grid on waste material that I can trust which has that accuracy.